# Transposing a 2D Array Only Works For Rectangular Arrays - Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a class with a method that transposes an array given the array, rows, and columns

```
public class Transpose {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = new int[6][5];

    System.out.println("Original:");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] += i+1;
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    transpose(array, 6, 5);
}

public static void transpose(int[][] array, int arrayRows, int arrayColumns)
{
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[arrayRows][arrayColumns];
    System.out.println("Transposed:");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            transposedArray[i][j] = array[j][i];
            System.out.print(transposedArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
Original:
1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 

Transposed:
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I realized that the method only works when the values of **arrayRows** and **arrayColumns** are the same value, for example: 6, 6 **or** 5, 5. I tried to place the values opposite of each other, the rows in columns and vice versa, however it did not work. How can I get the method to work for non-rectangular/square arrays?

Comment: When you transpose a matrix, the dimensions are transposed, too.  For example, the correct transpose of your 6x5 matrix would have dimensions 5x6.  You are trying to give the transpose the same dimensions as the original.  That works for square matrices because their two dimensions are the same, but it does not work for others.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, this explanation helped me understand well. The answer I also received made it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See line comments for explanation. Those are the only lines I modified.

```
public static void transpose(int[][] array, int arrayRows, int arrayColumns) {
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[arrayColumns][arrayRows]; //swap number of rows and columns
    System.out.println("Transposed:");
    for (int i = 0; i < transposedArray.length; i++) { //take the length of transposedArray, not array
        for (int j = 0; j < transposedArray[i].length; j++) { //take the length of transposedArray, not array
            transposedArray[i][j] = array[j][i];
            System.out.print(transposedArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly. I also clearly understand the logic behind it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the places of `arrayRows` and `arrayColumns` in the transposed matrix, because the new matrix is supposed to be a `[5][6]` instead of a `[6][5]`.

So your line of

```
int[][] transposedArray = new int[arrayRows][arrayColumns];
```

becomes

```
int[][] transposedArray = new int[arrayColumns][arrayRows];
```

We also need to swap `i` and `j` in the following statement, because the loops are following the indices of the original matrix:

```
transposedArray[i][j] = array[j][i];
```

to

```
transposedArray[j][i] = array[i][j];
```

And lastly, you can't print the transposed matrix while you're creating it as you're doing now, because you're just re-printing the original matrix that way. I suggest printing the matrix after you're done creating it.

With these changes, your code ends up like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = new int[6][5];

    System.out.println("Original:");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] += i+1;
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    transpose(array, 6, 5);
}

public static void transpose(int[][] array, int arrayRows, int arrayColumns)
{
    int[][] transposedArray = new int[arrayColumns][arrayRows];
    System.out.println("Transposed:");
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            transposedArray[j][i] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < transposedArray.length; i++) { //print the transposed matrix
        for(int j = 0; j < transposedArray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(transposedArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You can see a working example [here](https://rextester.com/VWVQZ2988).

Comment: This really helped as well. Thank you for taking the team to thoroughly explain :)

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` 
   // should count the number of rows. = 6
iterating from 0 ... 5

```
for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) // should count the number of columns = 5
```

iterate from 0..4

```
transposedArray[i][j] = array[j][i];
```

to access 6 ... you need j=5 ; i = 0...4
your loops are not able to access the values